# Showing/Hide Tabs and Section Based On Checkbox Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui

I am working on a form and want to `show/hide` tabs and their sections based on checkbox value. The code I have kind of works, but if you notice that when you check the three checkboxes, it unhides 3 tabs but it also shows all three sections displayed under the first tab. If you click on any of the tabs after un-hiding, it works fine. It's just that initial un-hiding that isn't working as I need it to. Here is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/jcaine04/HyMBD/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        /*
        **********************
        *   Initialization   *
        **********************
        */

        $("#contractTypes").tabs(); //create the tabs
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ //date picker code
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });

        //if UA Checkbox not checked, hide the section
        if (!$("#OBKey_Use_Agreement_Required").is(':checked')){
            $(".UASection").hide();
        }
        //if Extranet Checkbox not checked, hide the section
        if (!$("#OBKey_Extranet_Access").is(':checked')){
            $(".extranetSection").hide();
        }
        //if MoveIt Checkbox not checked, hide the section
        if (!$("#OBKey_Move_It_Access").is(':checked')){
            $(".moveItSection").hide();
        }


        /*
        **********************
        * End Initialization *
        **********************
        */

        //hide/show UA Section
        $("#OBKey_Use_Agreement_Required").click(function() {
            if ($("#OBKey_Use_Agreement_Required").is(":checked"))
            {
                $(".UASection").show("fast");
            } else {
                //otherwise hide it
                $(".UASection").hide("fast");
            }

        });

        //hide/show Extranet Section
        $("#OBKey_Extranet_Access").click(function() {
            if ($("#OBKey_Extranet_Access").is(":checked"))
            {
                //show hidden class
                //$(" #tabs ").tabs( "enable", 1 ); 
                $(".extranetSection").show("fast");
                //$("#tabs").tabs("select", "#UASection");

            } else {
                //otherwise hide it
                $(".extranetSection").hide("fast");
            }

        });

        //hide/show Move It Section
        $("#OBKey_Move_It_Access").click(function() {
            if ($("#OBKey_Move_It_Access").is(":checked"))
            {
                //show hidden class
                $(".moveItSection").show("fast");
                //$("#tabs").tabs("select", "#UASection");

            } else {
                //otherwise hide it
                $(".moveItSection").hide("fast");
            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: You can do tabs w/o JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/h633h/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh) call to your code:

```
$("#OBKey_Use_Agreement_Required,#OBKey_Extranet_Access,#OBKey_Move_It_Access").click(function () {
    $("#contractTypes").tabs("refresh");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HyMBD/2/)**

From the docs:

> Process any tabs that were added or removed directly in the DOM and
>   recompute the height of the tab panels.

Comment: Instead of using the `click` action do you think `change` would be better. `.on('change', function () {`